# apt-cyg is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cygwin

I installed cygwin on Windows10 and it works fine. Then I install apt-cyg package manager. The problem is apt-cyg is not recognized when running it from command prompt, but it works when I run it from cygwin terminal.  All other basic cygwin command is working fine in windows command prompt except apt-cyg.
What is wrong ?

Comment: You need to [edit] the question to show *how* you installed `apt-cyg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ file apt-cyg
apt-cyg: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

As it is a bash script, CMD does not know how to handle it; CMD only knows how to handles `.exe` cygwin programs.

Cygwin terminal runs bash shell interpreter, that of course knows how to manage a bash script. Also the other cygwin shell interpreters know how to rise bash for the execution of cyg-apt following the `#!` mechanism

```
$ head -n 1 apt-cyg
#!/bin/bash
```